# How to make TransformationFunctions work with Simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Here is a transformation function that replaces `f` with a polynomial:

```
expansion = Function[# /. f[a_, b_, c_] :> 
  Expand[a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2 a b - 2 a c - 2 b c]];
```

As you can see, applying `expansion` on the following expression leads to a simplification:

```
expr = (x^2 - y^2 + z)^2 - f[x^2, y^2, z];

expr // expansion // Simplify
```

> ```
> (*4 x^2 z*)
> ```

**Question:** However, adding `expansion` to `TransformationFunctions` doesn't work (why not?):

```
Simplify[expr, TransformationFunctions->{Automatic, expansion}]
```

> ```
> (x^2 - y^2 + z)^2 - f[x^2, y^2, z]
> ```

**Note:**  I compared the [built-in](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html?q=ComplexityFunction) `ComplexityFunction` for the two forms, and made sure the `4 x^2 z` indeed is simpler:

```
SimplifyCount[(x^2 - y^2 + z)^2 - f[x^2, y^2, z]]
SimplifyCount[4 x^2 z]
```

> ```
> (*25*) 
> (*6*)
> ```

I must not done something correctly.  Help please?

Comment: `FullSimplify[expr, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, expansion}]` gives the answer `4 x^2 z` immediately.

Comment: `g[a_, b_, c_] := a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2 a b - 2 a c - 2 b c
expr = (x^2 - y^2 + z)^2 - g[x^2, y^2, z] // Simplify;
Simplify[expr, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, expansion}]`. I think this works.

Comment: @QuantumDot, this works `Simplify[h[x], TransformationFunctions -> ((# /. h[a_] :> 1 a) &)]`, but this does not `Simplify[h[x], TransformationFunctions -> ((# /. h[a_] :> 2 a) &)]`. Looks like a bug?